# How Use Loop inside Function to rewrite elements inside massive?

Tags: python

I just start learning Python 1 week ago and I did one homework and think about how I can make it with massive and function. I wrote may be more then 200 lines of code but cant sole this. 
This code change first meaning in massive but not go on other elements. may be some one can teach me and show some professional things. )

```
number = int(input())
number2 = int(input())
number3 = int(input())

def OddEven():
    i = 0
    while i < 3:

        if (numArray[i] % 2) == 0:
            numArray[i] = 'even'
            return numArray[i]
            # return numArray[0]
        i += 1
numArray = [number, number2, number3]
OddEven()
print(numArray[0], numArray[1], numArray[2])
```

Comment: What do u mean by 'massive' ?

Comment: What is your question? What is your code supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the function inside `if` block. What it does is that it returns the value and gets out of the function. Meaning, that the code after the return statement will not be executed. Therefore, if the first value is even, it is returned and the rest of the code (inside function) will not be executed. Just remove the return statement and your code will work fine.

## Code

```py
number = int(input())
number2 = int(input())
number3 = int(input())

def OddEven():
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        if (numArray[i] % 2) == 0:
            numArray[i] = 'even'
            # Return statement removed
        i += 1
numArray = [number, number2, number3]
OddEven()
print(numArray[0], numArray[1], numArray[2])
```

## Input

```py
2
4
3
```

## Output

```py
even even 3
```

Comment: Glad to know. Don't forget to mark it as the right answer if it worked for you so that others can find the solution easily! :)

Comment: Please don’t recommend anti-patterns. Iteration using a while loop and manual increment is very bad style - it is slow, fragile and not generic. Always prefer a for loop unless absolutely necessary. To iterate with indices, use enumerate; instead of modifying the initial list by index, consider creating a new list. A list comprehension or generator is appropriate here.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi notes taken! For a beginner, I believe it's better to just show what is wrong with their code rather than introducing new or higher level concepts. But, I will definitely follow your suggestions next time.

Answer (score -1):

As someone new to programming, I don't expect you to know about function scopes and global variables but the tutorial you are following should teach you about them.

The problem is that in your `OddEven()` function, the variable `numArray` is not defined. In Python, any variables you make outside your function will not be accessible in the function. Therefore you must either add a parameter to your function or you can make your `numArray` variable a global variable.

The better practice is to use parameters. If you don't know, parameters are variables you pass to your functions. To add a parameter, you can rewrite your code like this:

`def OddEven(array):` Anything you put in between the brackets is considered a parameter, you can separate parameters using commas (,).

Theses parameters are nothing complicated. They are used exactly like normal variables, except you can't assign a new to value to them(but you can modify them). Just make sure to replace `numArray` with your parameter name.

You can now call the function like this: `OddEven(numArray)`.

Also when you return a variable from a function, it is best to store it in a variable like so: `newArray = OddEven(numArray)`, otherwise the function will be considered useless. Good luck on your programming journey!

Edit: If you `return` from a function, you will stop it. So it is best to just store the values in another array and then return the array from the function.

Comment: numArray is visible inside the function. Only writing to a global requires declaring it as such - reading is possible without a global declaration.